# Nicescroll jquery scrollend function not working. Getting as undefined. Using beat version jquery only

Tags: jquery, nicescroll

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // var nice = $("html").niceScroll();  // The document page (body)
  var scroll_var = $(".panel").niceScroll({ 
          cursorborder:"",
          cursorcolor:"#00F",
          boxzoom:true
  });

  scroll_var.scrollend(function(){

  });

});
```

Getting scrollend is undefined.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable.  Its not possible to tell if there is a typo here or just bad formatting...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can even access that function. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel").niceScroll({ 
          cursorborder:"",
          cursorcolor:"#00F",
          boxzoom:true
  });

  $(".panel").getNiceScroll().scrollend(function(){

  });

});
```

Comment: getNiceScroll(...).scrollend is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You only have to pass "info" as parameter it will returns an object with x,y current position and also the event scroll ends

```
$(".panel").onscrollend = function(info) {
          console.log("Scroll end")
          console.log(info)
}
```